# Error en Switch case en Java

Tags: java, netbeans-11

Estoy realizando un ejercicio simple pero me muestra unos íconos de errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué se está haciendo mal? Estoy siguiendo todos los pasos correctos, no observo que exista errores de sintaxis de código.

Este es el código:

```
package exampleswitch;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleSwitch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char cuestionario;
        cuestionario = 'Tema:';
        int semana;
        semana = 1;
        
        switch(semana){
            case 1:
                cuestionario += 'Introducción a la programación';
                break;
            case 2:
                cuestionario += 'Secuenciación y selección';
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tu caso, no es posible utilizar `char`. `Char` sirve para almacenenar un carácter como por ejemplo `'a'` o `'A'` con comillas simples.

Ahora para almacenar un conjuntos de caracteres, se utiliza `String`. Este tipo usualmente va entre comillas dobles `""`

Te dejo tu ejemplo de como quedaría:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleSwitch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Ten en cuenta que puedes declarar e inicializar la variable en una misma linea
       //Añade un espacio en blanco para que al concatenar no salga junta las palabras
        String cuestionario = "Tema: ";
        int semana;
        semana = 1;

        switch(semana){
            case 1:
                cuestionario += "Introducción a la programación";
                break;
            case 2:
                cuestionario += "Secuenciación y selección";
                break;//Añadido tambien el break en el 2º case
        }
    }
}
```

Te he dejado una serie de comentarios en tu código. Si tienes alguna *duda/problema* no temas en preguntar.

Comment: Gracias por darme una respuesta yo pensé que con eso se definía ya esté los caracteres me has dado algunos trucos a la vez... Estoy recién iniciando en este lenguaje pero si conozco otros que más o menos lo sé usar como PHP. Pero que error el mío. Gracias nuevamente Saludos.

Answer (score 14):

Estás definiendo la variable cuestionario como un char. Es decir, un carácter. Para múltiples caracteres, necesitas un string (o un arreglo de char, pero no creo que sea lo que buscas).

Cambia la definición de la variable para que sea de tipo string.

Edito porque hay un comentario muy importante: al manejar múltiples caracteres, se usan comillas dobles para demarcarlos.

```
String cuestionario;
cuestionario += "Introducción a la programación";
```

Comment: Agregando a esta respuesta: un string usa comillas dobles

Comment: @Alfabravo Le agradezco el tiempo de haber emitido una respuesta +1, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Estas definiendo mal, debería ser:

```
String cuestionario;
cuestionario = "Tema:";
```

Comment: Considera por favor agregar una explicación a tu respuesta